# <hr> between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on time i show up divs one by one.

I do this with jquery with

```
$("#section_"+index).show();
```

My divs have id's like:
section_1, section_2, section_3 etc.

i have the var currentSection which is the id of the last one that is shown.
Now i want a hr (horizontal ruler) between the last one shown and the previous one.
And if it shows the next one the old hr should be removed and a new hr should be shown.

Can this be done with jquery?

Comment: "section_x" as ids are horrible

Comment: This can be done using pure CSS: `[id^="section"]:last-of-type {border-top: 2px solid #000;}`.

Comment: @RobW not supported on IE. (<=8)

Comment: @RobW - My guess is we'll have to wait a few more years to see full support for such selectors in all browsers.

Comment: For reference, here's the compat table: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html. My suggested selector (remove postfix `-of-type`) can also be used as a jQuery selector, for example to add a class for the "hr".

Comment: @RobW - Yes, this selector will work when used in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, add:

```
.latest {
    border-top: 1px solid #888;
}
```

In your JS, change you show statement to:

```
$('.latest').removeClass('latest');
$("#section_"+index).addClass('latest').show();
```

Comment: I recommend `[id^="section_"]:last` instead of `#section_` ;)

Comment: Yes, that will work as well. Even if index is not known at the time.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [techfoobar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8869853/990877), you could do something like this:

```
$.fn.showNext = function(selector, delay) {
    var previous = this;
    var next = this.next();

    if (next.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            previous.removeClass('latest');
            next.addClass('latest').show().showNext(selector, delay);
        }, delay);
    }
};

$('.section').first().show().showNext('.section', 2000);
```

That way, you don't need those impractical `section_n` indexes. Demo [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/kZ28Q/).

Comment: thanks, i need the section_n for more stuff but your post was helpfull anyway.